# Facebook's Design Pattern, How? (load post and last 2 comments) so quickly?

Tags: facebook, design-patterns

Im creating a simple app, for internal use, with basic (facebook like) functionality, i have a wall, where users can create a 'post' and then other users can comment.

Here's how i design it, When i create a post, its added to the 'PostTbl'
and when a comment is made its added to the 'CommentsTbl'

As i load all post, in the SQL statement i also do a Count() for number of comments for each post.

so now the web page loads with just the post, and with a link to view comments. when they click on 'comments' then i do a AJAX call to load comments for that post to the page.

But facebook so quickly loads POST and Last 2 Comments, immediately...

Anyone have an idea what do you think is their design pattern that they can easily do this so efficiently?

thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it not the case that in Facebook when the number of comments are less than X (I can't remember the number off the top of my head) then it will display them immediately when you click to see more. However when there are more than X comments it actually takes you to dedicated story page which has a listing of all the recent comments.
This suggests that in the former example, all of the comments are pre-fetched but just hidden from view.

Comment: interesting idea, load all post, for each post, load comments to the post in the BG and then just display the latest 2 with a link to view all, could work, provided we only load 10 latest post per page...